# Does compiling a less file from a WordPress Child theme accomplish SEO-friendly source?

Tags: css, wordpress, seo, wordpress-theming, less

I am new here as a member. All of this communities questions and answers have taught me so much. This is probably an amateur CSS question, but does compiling a less file help get rid of all the CSS before headings etc for SEO optimization? I make "child themes" in WordPress but there is so much CSS in the source before the content I was wondering if a less file helps compress that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases LESS will help you to write compacter and so smaller CSS. Cause you are talking about inline CSS, smaller CSS while make your total content smaller which will load faster. SE's will like pages which load fast.

You could consider to read this https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery. Also discussed here: ["Eliminate render-blocking CSS in above-the-fold content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761251/eliminate-render-blocking-css-in-above-the-fold-content)

Why do you child themes have so much inline css in the first place, can't you add this to your  style.css? From http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes:

```
/*
 Theme Name:     Twenty Thirteen Child
 Theme URI:      http://example.com/twenty-thirteen-child/
 Description:    Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
 Author:         John Doe
 Author URI:     http://example.com
 Template:       twentythirteen
 Version:        1.0.0
*/

@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I know there are various strings about this online but I highly trust the answers on this website. I know a decent amount of SEO but I am working under an SEO "guru" for a WP site and he was complaining about all the inline CSS. I think the simplicity of calling the style sheet(s) from the child theme is exactly what will help. Yes load time is a big deal. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS files aren't included in most SEO metrics, nor is the structure of the CSS code looked at by anything other than the web browser when interpreting the file. Instead, **how** the CSS effects page content is more relevant.

There are plenty of links online that talk about this so no need to rehash that here.