# Google PageSpeed optimization issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagespeed

I am doing some Google PageSpeed-"Driven" enhancements to our company website. I just ran into an issue I am having a hard time figuring out.

We use filerev and usemin for versioning of our CSS and Javascript files. One of the main aims of Google PageSpeed seems to be above-the-fold optimization, that is how fast can the page be rendered and how complete will be the web page be on the first request. One way to increase speed and make GPS happy is to put all CSS inline in index.html. Now this doesn't work that well with versioning.

What am I missing? I can't be the only one facing this issue? Is there a way to trick the cache to reload a cached page before the expiration date?

Comment: don't care about this thing, keep your CSS external will save you much time

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702199/loading-css-in-my-page-eficiently/