# Reduce “Eliminate render-blocking CSS in above-the-fold content" for Desktop

Tags: css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am working on googlepagespeed for the my website. Earlier my website speed is, **IN MOBILE-86** and **IN DESKTOP-93**.  I have seen ["Eliminate render-blocking CSS in above-the-fold content"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761251/eliminate-render-blocking-css-in-above-the-fold-content) link. I have implemented https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery. So right now I am loading my css through with **noscript**. So my website increased score with **IN MOBILE-96** and **DESKTOP-93**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
    <noscript id="deferred-styles">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css"/>
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
      else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But desktop score is contant. My website link is https://www.winni.in/cake-delivery-in-bangalore.

***FOR MOBILE:***
[image]

***FOR DESKTOP:***
[image]

I want to know "*Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content warning*" showing in only desktop,  Not in mobile screen. But URL is same. Before implemented this concept **noscript**(https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) "*Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content warning*" showing in bothy screen. So why it is not reflect in desktop screen

Answer (score 0):

**.woff font files are considered CSS.**  All CSS must be loaded before JavaScript.

[image: Waterfall]