# How to improve page speed in google?

Tags: javascript, css

I have minified js and css and optimized images. Used async="async" in js where it is applicable.

How to fix "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try calling your scripts at the bottom of the page and make a work around for document ready functions if there are any.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "above-the-fold content" in Google Pagespeed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340402/what-is-above-the-fold-content-in-google-pagespeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render means loading, so if something is render-blocking, it means that it is keeping the page from loading as quickly as it could.

1) load css in the headers but Js in the footer

2) Use sprite images

3) You can add htaccess code for for better performance

- Gzip compression
- set Expires and Cache-Control headers
- Browser cache-control

4) Load only required css/js on pages

Choose Best Method
Once you’ve identified which scripts need to be moved it is time to decide “how” to fix them. There are two main methods to choose from. The first is to make the scripts inlined; in this method the contents of the script are added directly into the HTML of the page and are only loaded once they are needed. This is the best option if the script is small and applies to a single page.

Another option is to defer the script. When you defer JavaScript you are delaying any non-essential scripts from loading until after the first render or until after the more essential portions have loaded. This method is best when the script is not crucial and can wait to load.

PS:- We can not resolve this fully in some cases.