# Lighthouse performance improvement for react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, lighthouse, google-pagespeed

I ran a lighthouse audit on the page via chrome dev-tools and got a very poor performance rating...

The unused JavaScript code is causing the score to fall.

The unused JS is mainly the node-modules functions & commented out code present in JS files present in node modules. Below is an example of that:
[image: Coverage report showing unused JS]

LightHouse score: here if you see the largest contentful paint, time to interactive and speed index are very poor, what Is causing this? I'm barely even doing anything..
[image: Score]

[image: Lighthouse report Opportunity]

How can we handle such unused Javascript code which is affecting the performance?
Thank you!

I have uninstalled unused node-modules and dev-dependency from application.

Comment: As suggested by lighthouse (in the last image you posted) you could look into [lazy loading in React](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/Suspense) (lazy/Suspence). There are also concepts like [tree-shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking) you could read up on. Then there is [above the fold rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340402/what-is-above-the-fold-content-in-google-pagespeed).